# How to assign the metadata for folders and sub folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am migrating the SharedFolders and files from Windows to SharePoint Library. So here i am able to add metadata for only files, but not for folders.
Here the below is the code i tried for adding metadata to the folders and subfolders.

```
 $item.CreationTime  for CreatedDate
 $item.LastWriteTime for ModifiedDate
 $ace = (Get-Acl $subfolder.FullName).Owner  for FileOwner fields.




$Folder = gci $folderpath -recurse 
    Write-Host "$Folder"
    #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
         foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder)
            {   
                if (($SubFolder.FullName).length -le 260)               
                {   
                Write-Host "$SubFolder"
                $item = Get-Item -literal $SubFolder.FullName
                Write-Host "$item"
                $item.CreationTime
                $item.LastWriteTime
                $ace = (Get-Acl $subfolder.FullName).Owner
                Write-Host "$ace"                
                }               
            }
```